# Matrix Multiplication C language

Tags: c

So, I have problem with matrix multiplication. I have to store the values of a matrix in a file and after that multiply them. The problem occurs when I try to multiply 900x900 matrix: Segmentation fault (core dumped), but 800x800 works perfectly). there is part of my code: create file for storing:

```
FILE *A, *B;
int num = atoi(argv[1]);
float a[num][num];
float b[num][num];
A = fopen(argv[2],"r");
B = fopen(argv[3],"r");
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        fscanf(A,"%f",&a[i][j]);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        fscanf(B,"%f",&b[i][j]);
    }
}
```

So i didn't write function for matrix multiplication because it works

Comment: You manually fill 800x800 matrix?

Comment: I use random function to fill matrix

Comment: You are loading the whole with into the memory, that’s the problem try to load a row and column at a time. Or you can use other language like python because matrix multiplication is really a complex job for cpu.

Comment: Maybe you are running out of stack space. Try using `malloc` instead of VLAs.

Comment: Yes, the two arrays require more than 6 Mbytes on the stack.

Comment: I would be interested to know what is `argv[1]` since you did not post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In any case , it is foolish not to check `argc` or the result of `fopen` for `A` and `B`. For user input, checking everything provided is *de rigueur*.

Comment: where is segmentation fault?

Comment: "didn't write function for matrix multiplication because it works" Superstition has a 10 to 1 chance that the problem is in that code you considered unneeded for your [mcve].

Comment: The question is not at all related to matrix multiplication; you should change the title.  Use a title that reflects the specific  problem - in this case "_segmentation fault using large array_" perhaps - rather than one that reflects the application in which you are having the problem.

Comment: @purec : Clearly not; the data is read from a file.

Answer (score 3):

Your two `float` variable-length arrays occupy 2*900<sup>2</sup>*4 bytes  - that is a little over 6Mb.  VLAs are typically created on the stack, the size of which will vary between systems and processes, but on a modern desktop system is typically perhaps 2 to 8 Mb.

Creating an array that large on the stack is somewhat unreasonable, and failure unsurprising.

Comment: Thank you) I used malloc instead of VLAs=)